# PHP mail script gives me syntax error

Tags: php, forms, email

Im trying to get my php mailer embedded on my html page, I get no syntax errors in Dreamweaver but sendmail (http://glob.com.au/sendmail/) keeps giving me this error message "Syntax error in arguments
" Im hoping you can help me nail the issue

My PHP mailer:

```
//Email information
$admin_email = "------------ Secret";
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
$comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];

//send email
mail($admin_email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $email);

//Email response
echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
}

//if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
else  {
?>
```

Here is the relevant page code

```
<?php
//if "email" variable is filled out, send email
  if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {

  //Email information
  $admin_email = "schlichtingr@yahoo.com";
  $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
  $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];

  //send email
  mail($admin_email, "$subject", $comment, "From:" . $email);

  //Email response
  echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
  }

  //if "email" variable is not filled out, display the form
  else  {
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id ="Email">         
    <form method="post"><br />
      <h3><b>send us a message</b></h3>
      <span>Any further questions or concerns? Send us an email!</span><br>
         Email: <input name="email" type="text" /><br />
         Subject: <input name="subject" type="text" /><br />
         Message:<br />
          <textarea name="comment" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </div>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Any help you can give me would be much appreciated
I am new to php but still trying to learn

Basically I just want to make a mail form built onto an html page

Comment: is that a PHP error, or an error from whatever smtp client php is trying to invoke to actually do the sending?

Comment: Try removing the quotes: "$subject" => $subject

Comment: Read up on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php - That's what the manual was put together for ;) Just like the 'ol VCR's. Never could quite figure out how to set the time without one.

Comment: You do realize that you're only checking `if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))` - If someone doesn't fill out the subject field, mail may very well be rejected or sent to Spam.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, not while I tested it. Check your mail logs, and add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with sendmail, but I notice 1 thing:

1. `"$subject"` needs to be just `$subject` . You are capturing that variable for a reason. So turning it into a string of "$subject" makes no sense to me.

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is no need for the action attribute, since the mailing script is in the same page. With no action attribute, the form submits to the current page.

Comment: Ah! Ok. Good point. Sorry. My php foo is rusty.  Will edit that one out.

Comment: `"$string"` and `$string` evaluate to the same thing because of [PHP string handling interpolation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double).

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
   //if "email" variable is filled out, send email
    if (isset($_REQUEST['email']))  {
     //Email information
     $admin_email = "user@example.com";
     $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
     $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
     $comment = $_REQUEST['comment'];
     $headers = "From: $email" . "\r\n";

     mail($admin_email, $subject, $comment, $headers);
     //Email response
     echo "Thank you for contacting us!";
    }
```